# Waiting processes in C

Tags: c, linux, process

I`m trying to implement management of 4 processes with signals. A parent forks 4 processes. An each child process registers its own signal handler and pauses. After that its required to write in terminal 0, 1, 2, 3 to start a needed process(using non canonical input).

My code:

Creating forks:

```
int pidArray[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
            case -1:
                perror("Fork failed");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        while (1) {
                            signal(SIGUSR1, changeRegister);
                            pause();
                        }
                        exit(0);
                    case 1:
                        while (1) {
                            signal(SIGUSR1, invertString);
                            pause();
                        }
                        exit(0);
                    case 2:
                        while (1) {
                            signal(SIGUSR1, replaceSymbols);
                            pause();
                        }
                        exit(0);
                    case 3:
                        while (1) {
                            signal(SIGUSR1, translateToKOI);
                            pause();
                        }
                        exit(0);
                }
                break;
            default:
                pidArray[i] = pid;
        }
    }
```

Infinite loop:

```
while (1) {
        if (!isatty(0)) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "stdin not terminal\n");
            exit(1); 
        };

        char ch;

        tcgetattr(0, &tty);
        savetty = tty;
        tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
        tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
        tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &tty);

        read(0, &ch, 1);
        tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &savetty);
        if (ch - '0' >= 0 && ch - '0' <= 3) {
            kill(pidArray[ch - '0'], SIGUSR1);
            wait(NULL);
        } else {
            perror("You entered wrong chararacter. Please right a number in range 0-3");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

So the problem is that  I can`t go back in a loop and keep doing
**kill(pidArray[ch - '0'],SIGUSR1);** invoking a needed signal. 
It works only once.

Example:

```
MacBook-Pro-Vadim:Fork vadim$ ./a.out
Enter name: Vadim
Name: Vadim

0
1
2
3
```

Seems like wait doesn`t work properly in this case or maybe I`m doing something wrong.

If I delete wait I encounter an error:

```
MacBook-Pro-Vadim:Fork vadim$ ./a.out
Enter name: You entered wrong chararacter. Please right a number in range 0-3: Undefined error: 0
Name: ?????
```

**EDIT 1**:
   Handler:

```
char *readString(buffer) {
    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    char *string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER);
    read(0, string, BUFFER);
    return string;
}

void changeRegister() {
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);  // read string
    printf("Name: ");
    puts(name);    // display string
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not complete.  What are the actual signal handler functions?  Also, note that you can only make calls to [async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).  And see this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471162/why-does-my-signal-handler-only-execute-once

Comment: @AndrewHenle edited, added 1 handler

Comment: You can't safely do those types of function calls in a signal handler.  `printf()`, `fgets()`, `puts()`, `malloc()` are all very async-signal-UNSAFE. [Per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188):  "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows for calling of async-signal-safe functions only.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)

Comment: @AndrewHenle so how should I read the string then?